# Node.js Connect middleware Limit not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem
server:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');

var app = connect()
.use(connect.limit('32kb'))
.use(connect.urlencoded())
.use(connect.json())
.use(function(req, res){
    console.log('yo');
    res.end('hello\n');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

client:

```
var http = require('http');

var req = http.request({
method: 'POST',
port: 3000,
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
});

req.write('[');
var n = 30000000;
while (n--) {
req.write('"foo",');
}
req.write('"bar"]');
req.end();
```

Connect's middleware limit not "limiting" size of json. I know that it will deprecated, but instead Express framework what can i use to limit a size of requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the limit middleware checks the header `Content-Length` of request message **only** while there's no such header out of your HTTP POST request.

You can verify this by using:

```
var app = connect()
.use(connect.limit('32kb'))
.use(connect.urlencoded())
.use(connect.json())
.use(function(req, res){
  console.log(req.headers);
  console.log('yo');
  res.end('hello\n');
});
```

You can test the `limit` middle via this code:

```
var http = require('http');

var req = http.request({
  method: 'POST',
  port: 3000,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': 40 * 1024
  }
});
```

BTW: you can check how the `limit` middleware is tested: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/test/limit.js

Comment: ok. but, i not receive any logs about errors or warning message, why? looks like nothing going on!

Comment: you should get warning like `connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0` out of your server console. but the error is represented by status code only without any message.

Comment: well, i get it. i mean my "client-server" still sending request with json to server! then for what need middleware console.limit? i think if its work, then something must going on, but i'm nothing see.

Comment: the middleware "limit" checks header entry "Content-Length" header only **without** checking messaging body at all. you know usually such request like want you initialized is illegal because header entry "Content-Length" is mandatory for POST request and should be sent prior to any data transfer. So you should send legal POST request to verify your expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

do this instead:

```
.use(connect.urlencoded({
  limit: '32kb'
}))
.use(connect.json({
  limit: '32kb'
}))
```

or just:

```
.use(connect.bodyParser({
  limit: '32kb'
})
```

you can still write to `req`, but that doesn't necessarily mean the server will receive those bytes. if you check the response and it isn't a 4xx error, then it's a bug.

EDIT:

```
req.once('response', function (res) {
  assert.equal(res.statusCode, 413)
})
.write(new Buffer(123123123213223122))
.end()
```

Comment: can you give me some example. i understand your explanation, but i can't understand how to read response from server at client-server instance of node.

Comment: I'm not understanding where this code must be inserted, sorry. terminal's output "this.parent = new SlowBuffer(this.length); assert is not defined" and so on...

Comment: @user2972298 the code in this answer does limit the size of the message body. you can insert the code into your code like `var app = connect().use(connect.limit('32kb')).use(connect.urlencoded({limit: '32kb'})).use(connect.json({limit: '32kb'}));`

Comment: Why is specifying the limit in the parsers better?